# How many times a number occurs

Tags: java

I need to write a program that reads an array of ints and an integer number *n*. The program must check how many times *n* occurs in the array.

Input:

The first line contains the size of the input array.

The second line contains elements of the array separated by spaces.

The third line contains n.

Output:

The result is only a single non-negative integer number.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[len];
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (array[i] == n) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Test input:

```
6

1 2 3 4 2 1

2
```

My result: **1**

My question is why `int n = scanner.nextInt();`read "1". It should "2".

Comment: In your code you read `int n = scanner.nextInt();` _before_ you fill the array, while in your input you first seem to enter the numbers for you array before you enter the the number it should count. As a result your `array` contains `[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2]` and `n` is `1`, so it will count the occurrences of `1` in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the *n* variable was in the wrong place. The solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[len];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int counter = 0;
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (array[i] == n) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read n after you read the array like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int len = scanner.nextInt();
int[] array = new int[len];

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}

int n = scanner.nextInt();

int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (array[i] == n) {
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println(counter);
```